# Maven hosting with Bintray

Tags: maven, bintray

I am having issues with hosting maven jars with Github (site-maven-plugin) so I want to move with Bintray asap.

What are the steps to host a existing maven jar in bintray?

**Here is my error when doing:** `mvn releae prepare`

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseFailureException: You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.
```

What I have now is I can do `mvn clean install` with no problems at all. Can I just upload the files under `./m2` repo? I basically uploaded the .jar and .pom I found in the maven repository.

- How can I access the library I uploaded on Bintray from my pom.xml?

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project myapplib: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.myapplib:myapplib:jar:0.0.1 from/to bintray-myorg-myapplib-myapplib (https://api.bintray.com/maven/myorg/myapplib/myapplib): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/myorg/myapplib/myapplib/org/myapplib/myapplib/0.0.1/myapplib-0.0.1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Comment: What problems do you experience with GitHub releases?

Comment: Here's what I found: http://veithen.github.io/2013/05/26/github-bintray-maven-release-plugin.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get started with publishing from Maven to Bintray by copy-pasting some pom parts from "Set Me Up" guide:
[image]

[Full user manual](https://bintray.com/docs/front/) is available as well.

Please note, that you can't upload SNAPSHOTs to Bintray. It's a distribution platform and it is not intended for development process. 
Saying that, you are welcome to take advantage of [a free Artifactory account](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425) for hosting your snapshot during development.

Using OJO you don't need to use the troublesome Maven Release Plugin anymore. Once you're satisfied with the snapshots quality you can [promote them to be releases and upload them to Bintray](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425#DeployingMavenandGradlesnapshotstoOJO%28oss.jfrog.org%29-build) in one REST call (or click of a button in Jenkins),

Comment: When approved for OJO, is there a OJO maven plugin like in Github's 'site-maven-plugin' which we can easily deploy maven artifacts. I'm having a hard time understanding Bintray or OJO compared to Github plugin.

Comment: You deploy to oss.jfrog.org by using regular maven deploy plugin (running `mvn deploy`) or by using [Artifactory Maven Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin).
You promote to Bintray by using promotion plugin in Jenkins or by REST (as described in the link I gave in the answer).